# Calculating a responsive header's height and using the result in the style of another div's height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Please bear with me as I attempt to explain the issue I'm having. It's kinda tricky!

I have a fixed header that includes a responsive image, because of this, the height of the header depends on the width of the device. I also have a fixed footer sitting on the bottom of the screen. In-between the header and footer I have a fixed div with scrollable overflow positioned towards the left side of the screen. I need the fixed div in-between the header and footer to have a HEIGHT that is the following:

calc(100% - the header's height in px - the footer's height in px)

To do this, I know I need to use Javascript or jQuery, but I'm unsure how to go about setting that up. Furthermore, I need that styling to only be applied on a specific media query.

I have similar code that adds padding to the top and bottom of another div that is centered between the header and footer. This is the code that I'm using and it works perfectly (in the fiddle I've provided at the bottom, I don't use "DOMContentLoaded" because it doesn't quite work with JSFiddle like it should. same idea slightly different syntax in the fiddle) :

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var headerHeight = document.getElementById('header').clientHeight;
    document.getElementById("content").style.paddingTop = headerHeight + "px";
    var footerHeight = document.getElementById('footer').clientHeight;
    document.getElementById("content").style.paddingBottom = footerHeight + "px";
    }, true);

    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    var headerHeight = document.getElementById('header').clientHeight;
    document.getElementById("content").style.paddingTop = headerHeight+ "px";
    var footerHeight = document.getElementById('footer').clientHeight;
    document.getElementById("content").style.paddingBottom = footerHeight + "px";
    }, true);
```

I need to use code similar to that, but instead of styling the div "content", I need to be styling a div titled "description" and instead of styling the padding, I need to be styling the height. The last difference is that the styling should only be applied to this media query:

```
@media screen and (orientation: landscape)
```

I've created a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yg7mjhvn/

Thank you guys so much! I really appreciate it.

Comment: You might find [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) useful for this layout. See [Flexbox with fixed header and footer and scrollable content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47659664/flexbox-with-fixed-header-and-footer-and-scrollable-content).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get it correctly, you just need to set the height of content/description div `calc(100% - <header-height> - <footer-height>)` with javascript.

So, to do that add a function setDescriptionHeight to your js code which sets the height of description div and add it as a load and resize event handler. All this will be done like this.

```
function setContentHeight() {
        if (window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight) {  // window.orientation === 90 for checking the real orientation
            var headerHeight = document.getElementById('header').clientHeight;
            var footerHeight = document.getElementById('footer').clientHeight;
            document.getElementById("description").style.height = `calc(100% -  ${headerHeight}px - ${footerHeight}px)`;
        } else{
            document.getElementById("description").style.height = "";    
        }
        document.getElementById("description").style.top = `${headerHeight}px`;
    }

window.addEventListener('load', setContentHeight, true);
window.addEventListener('resize', setContentHeight, true);
```

Now, you see that it has a condition `window.orientation === 90`. That is there to check whether the device is in landscape orientation, and if it is then the styling is done.

**note** that `window.innerHeight < window.innerWidth`  simply detects whether the width is greater than the height. And, `window.orientation === 90` checks the device orientation and it won't be 90 for a laptop or a dekstop screen. Moreover, it is deprecated now and you can see more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/orientation)

Comment: Thank you so much for all the information!! As soon as I get home, I will try this out and let you know how it worked! :)

Comment: Hello @ammar , I was able to try out the code, but I wasn't able to get it to work unfortunately. I also tried changing all the times you used "content" to "description" and that didn't seem to work either. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: @JohnSmith see the edited answer. i think that you'll have to do `window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight` in your case

Comment: Sounds good! I'll try this out and let you know! I appreciate it :)

Comment: Updated answer worked perfectly. Thanks x100! To clarify, will this code work if a phone gets rotated into landscape mode?

Comment: @JohnSmith yes it would

Comment: Thank you so much! Also, you're 16?! That's crazy. Keep up the great work man.