# How to make the scrollbar occupy 100% height of the viewport height when using flexbox for layout

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, scrollbar

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47661523/9953550). The layout is working well but I am trying to have my implementation have a scrollbar that occupies 100% of the page(100vh). If you look at the answer's scrollbar it occupies the full height minus the header's and footer's part. How can I have a scrollbar that occupies 100% of the page?

I have tried putting the height of the scrollbar to 100vh using [this sandbox](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_custom_scrollbar), but it didn't work.

Is what I am trying possible using flexbox, if so how do I do it?

Comment: Scrollbars are set to the height of the scrollable area for very good UI & UX reasons. Even if it were possible, why?

Comment: I gave the example in the question, but I had to write my code in a different way...