# angular/ng-bootstrap/css How to prevent to use the first 100px for any display but a header which is set as fixed-top?

Tags: css, angular, viewport, ng-bootstrap

**angular/ng-bootstrap** context :

probably obvious answers for you experts but I tried since many days without success yet.

My header in fixed-top configuration is correctly displayed.
My Content in a container is  also properly displayed with a top margin until I scroll down to a defined fragment by its id (like http://somewhere.com/page#fragment)
At this point, the browser jumps to the section but displays it at the top of the viewport which below the header and then makes it hidden by the header.
So I'd like to find a way to ban the top zone to be used by something else than the header.
Thx for any help in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually not sure what is "fixed-top configuration". Here is [a nice solution for your markup requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47661523/390161). It is a simple one and works without bootstrap or any other dependencies.

And take a look at the comment to that answer. There is an accessibility remark there.

Comment: The solution suggests flex in vertical orientation, using 100% height of remaiing space, overflow for scrolling ..  
Did not try that yet ..  
I'll follow with a quick check very soon with href to anchor/fragments !  
However, before coding and as i am using ng-bootstrap (boarding bootstrap), i wonder what bootstrap semantic can be used to aim same result ?

Comment: btw "fixed-top" as per bootstrap usage :  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/position/#fixed-top