# Element "tucked" under another element...and it shouldn't

Tags: css, blazor, blazor-server-side

*This should be a CSS style question, but it has some C#/Blazor components...that's why I tagged both.*

Here my main layout:

```
<div class="container-fluid p-0 d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
  <div class="navbar fixed-top">This is the header</div>
  <div class="content flex-grow-1">
    @Body
  </div>
  <div class="navbar tiny-text fixed-bottom d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div id="footer_div">This is the footer</div>
</div>
```

My problem is that whatever component that I have that takes place in **@Body** will appear "under" the header bar (*even it's just a simple div or span*).  My workaround right now is use css' top to avoid the header.  What do I have to do, so that the elements in the div won't start from underneath the header element?

Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry, Is not it how it is supposed to work, header>body>footer ?
Am i missing something

Comment: @ZiaAhmad...the header/footer/body are just semantics...I can call them whatever I want...the problem here is that the middle element seems to span the whole viewport, thus causing its element to show up underneath the header.  Hope this helps.

Comment: please include a screenshot, but from what i understand, you should add margin-top = header height on elements after header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `fixed-top` from your `navbar` element the body will no longer "tuck" under the header.

```razor
<div class="container-fluid p-0 d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
  <div class="navbar">This is the header</div>
  <div class="content flex-grow-1">
    @Body
  </div>
  <div class="navbar tiny-text fixed-bottom d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div id="footer_div">This is the footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to retain the fixed-like header and footer you should be able to use something like the below adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47661523/12189828)

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<header class="navbar">This is the header</header>
<main class="content flex-grow-1">
  @Body
</main>
<footer class="navbar tiny-text d-flex justify-content-center">
  <section>This is the footer</section>
</footer>
```

Comment: I accept this answer thought it introduces a side-effect...when I scroll, I lose the header.  The good thing is that I am building a single-page app, so no scroll should be allowed any way....

Comment: I believe the body would also "tuck" under the footer content if it was long enough due to ```fixed-bottom```. I have added an edit with an adaptation from another answer mimicking the fixed header and footer behavior with flex.

Comment: I took your first recommendation and apply h-100 to the middle div (body), the bottom remained as fixed-bottom and everything looks great!  Thank you for the lead!

Answer (score 1):

To keep elements in normal flow don’t give them *position: fixed, or position: absolute.* **Use float: right and float: left.** IF you have a header that is fixed or absolute, then the normal flow that follows that element will need a margin-top equal to or slightly greater than the height of the header div element. The margin will ‘fill’ the space behind the fixed/absolute element.

Comment: @Nikhil...thx for the prompt reply...as you can see the "header" does not call out the height explicitly...in this case what's my option for defining the margin-top?  thanks again!

Comment: @Nikhil...thanks for following up...I took the lead given by Douglas Riddle and everything  is working out now.