# Common Header and Footer in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am new to Next.js and don't know what is the correct approach. When I go to another page I want to display my Header and Footer always to stay on the page.

My folder structure look like this -
[folder structure screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4ZUh.png)

**Layout.js**

```
import Nav from "./Nav";
import Footer from "./Footer";

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {/* <Nav /> */}
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
            <h1>i am layout</h1>
            {children}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* <Footer /> */}
    </>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

**Index.js**

```
import Head from "next/head";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.dvHeader}>
      <Head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <meta name="description" content="This is about page" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="html, css, javascript" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <h1>i am index.js</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**_app.js**

```
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import "../styles/globals.css";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flexbox with fixed header and footer and scrollable content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47659664/flexbox-with-fixed-header-and-footer-and-scrollable-content) - The only difference is that the root element id in next is `__next`.

Comment: No, When I click and go to another page I want to keep the header and footer on the page.

Comment: Uncomment the `Nav` and `Footer` components in `Layout.js` to show them on every page. Here is an article outlining different options for layouts in Next - https://adamwathan.me/2019/10/17/persistent-layout-patterns-in-nextjs/