# CSS layout with header (fixed), body split in menu (scrollable) and content (scrollable), footer (fixed)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I feel like that question has been asked a few times already but I haven't been able to find an answer to that specific use case.

Here's what I want:

[image]

I think the closest post/answer I've been able to find is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47661523/2398593).

I understand and am able to repro it without any issue, see [stackblitz live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-a6ks6n?file=index.html).

But as soon as I try to split the main panel into 2 different panels with a left menu and the content, I get a scrollbar on the right and the footer is being pushed right below. I have to scroll to see the footer whereas I only want to be able to scroll in both the left menu and the content but always want to see the header and footer.

Here's my attempt on [stackblitz as a minimal repro](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-macyby?file=styles.css) to show the issue.

About the code:

```css
html,
body {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.body {
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.body .menu {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}

.body .content {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">header</div>

  <div class="body">
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <!-- duplicate this as many times as needed to verify scrolling behavior -->
        <li>Menu Item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <ul>
        <!-- duplicate this as many times as needed to verify scrolling behavior -->
        <li>Content Item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think the only decent way to achieve this would be to have a fixed width for your left column

Comment: I think I could live with a fixed width on the left column, that said I do not understand how that'd help in any way. Feel free to post a proper answer with a demo to go more in depth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can fix the width of your left column then you can use absolute positioning on your middle divs to get the overflow you want:

```css
html,
body {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.body {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.body .menu {
  width: 200px;
}

.body .content {
  flex: 1;
}

.scroll-holder {
  position: relative;
}

.scroll {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.test {
   height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">header</div>

  <div class="body">
    <div class="menu scroll-holder">
      <div class="scroll">
        <ul>
          <!-- duplicate this as many times as needed to verify scrolling behavior -->
          <li class="test">Menu Item</li>
          <li>Menu Item</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content scroll-holder">
      <div class="scroll">
        <ul>
          <!-- duplicate this as many times as needed to verify scrolling behavior -->
          <li class="test">Content Item</li>
          <li>Content Item</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

With a fluid left column:

```css
html,
body {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.body {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.body .content {
  flex: 1;
}

.absolute-flex {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.scroll {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.test {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">header</div>

  <div class="body">
    <div class="absolute-flex">
      <div class="menu scroll">
        <ul>
          <!-- duplicate this as many times as needed to verify scrolling behavior -->
          <li class="test">Menu Item</li>
          <li>Menu Item</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="content scroll">
        <ul>
          <!-- duplicate this as many times as needed to verify scrolling behavior -->
          <li class="test">Content Item</li>
          <li>Content Item</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good indeed. I don't understand why the width of the left column matters that much though?

Comment: If you didn't have that width then as there is no content in either column (as they are both absolutely positioned) they would just sit on top of each other with the left column taking no width and the right column being 100% width as it has the flex grow

Comment: Uuuumh I see that makes more sense. Thanks! I'm not necessarily stuck with flex layout, would the above be easier with a grid for example (I'm really not familiar with grids I'm afraid...) or would I have to define the height of the header/footer and I should rather stick with a flexbox?

Comment: I've not really tried grid myself as it doesn't work in my company's supported browser list so wouldn't be able to say

Comment: I've found a way for your left column to have a fluid width - see edit above

Comment: Ok for the grid. And wow the edit looks perfect to me, thanks for the help

Comment: @Pete that's a fantastic solution Great Job.

Answer (score 0):

I think this demo should solve the issue.
[stackblitz-demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-z26z9p?file=index.html)

The trick is to hide the overflow on the body, but only make it to auto on the div you want to scroll in. Then you have to define the height you want that div to be and you should be able to scroll when an overflow occurs. :)

Comment: Thanks for having a go at it. That said, the footer isn't visible anymore (and that's my main issue) and now the left menu and content don't have the same size as well

Comment: For me the footer is actually visible, because I probably use a bigger monitor (on my laptop it is hidden too). You just have to adjust the height of the two containers (menu and content) to make them the same height and to make the footer visible. Best would be of course to make it responsive, so you can see the footer on multiple devices.

Comment: I want that layout to be responsive. Nothing will have a fixed height here

Comment: https://web-platform-uf2xj3.stackblitz.io is this what you want?

Comment: Please share the link including the IDE, not only the demo. Edit, here it is: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-uf2xj3?file=index.html

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-z26z9p?file=index.html sorry, forgot about that

Comment: Better but same answer as I made to k-devs above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73290974/css-layout-with-header-fixed-body-split-in-menu-scrollable-and-content-scr/73291054?noredirect=1#comment129435088_73291181

Comment: `height: 90vh;` is not something I can accept I'm afraid

Comment: Oh ok, sorry. 90 vh should be very responsive tho, since it refers to the device height. But I understand.

Comment: All good, thanks for trying though! It's not good enough because I could have something quite big to show in the footer for example. In which case even 90% wouldn't enough. But I don't want to make that like 60% otherwise I'll loose too much space

Answer (score 0):

The height and position attributes are the main things you should play around with.

```css
    html,
    body {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      max-height: 100vh;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      height: 80%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    .body {
      flex: 1;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
    }

    .body .menu {
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      overflow: auto;
    }

    .body .content {
      max-height: 100%;
      flex: 50%;
      justify-content: space-around;
      overflow: auto;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="header">header</div>

      <div class="body">
        <div class="menu">
          <ul>
            <!-- duplicate this as many times as needed to verify scrolling behavior -->
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
            <li>Menu Item</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <ul>
            <!-- duplicate this as many times as needed to verify scrolling behavior -->
            <li>Content Item</li>
            <li>Content Item</li>
            <li>Content Item</li>
            <li>Content Item</li>
            <li>Content Item</li>
            <li>Content Item</li>
            <li>Content Item</li>
            <li>Content Item</li>
            <li>Content Item</li>
            <li>Content Item</li>
            <li>Content Item</li>
            <li>Content Item</li>
            <li>Content Item</li>
            <li>Content Item</li>
            <li>Content Item</li>
            <li>Content Item</li>
            <li>Content Item</li>
            <li>Content Item</li>
            <li>Content Item</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="footer">footer</div>
    </div>
```

you might still need to play around to get the result you want.

Comment: Thanks k-devs! It looks better than other solutions I've seen but I'm afraid what makes the diff is the `height: 80%;` and I would like to not have this as I can insert big or small components in both header and footer. I need something really responsive there

Comment: Your welcome,  Maybe consider using css grid, i think its a better choice here! or maybe make the footer and header fixed.

Comment: I think it'll be the same issue with grids, isn't? I gave it a go but then felt like I'd have to specify the header and footer height with grids as well

Comment: The reason the footer was sliding down was because the height of .body div  + height of the header + height of the footer was greater than that of the body tag.  i don't really think using % or vh for the height will make your site unresponsive b/c the height of the body is always equal to the view port height doesnt matter if its long or short. i really don't think using % or vh for the height will be a problem responsive wise. its width you might need to worry about. try it on multiple devices!

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/73291497/2398593 it's exactly what I'm after, I think you'll notice the diff if you play with the size of the window it's always looking good

Comment: How do you want your footer to behave if you add large content in it, do you want the .body div to shrink or the footer to have scrolling?

Comment: header and footer should be able to take as much space as they want, the "body" (containing left menu + content) should adjust based on them

Comment: Have a look at Pete's edited answer, it's doing all this :) thanks for the help anyway k-devs!

Comment: My pleasure. Btw  that's a great answer, i'll make sure to use it in the future.